# Working with windows Azure active directory

Tags: c#, azure, active-directory

Can any one suggest me a place to get started to work with Windows Azure directory and GraphClient.May be a blog or video.

I googled and I could not find any valuable resources.I referred to [this](http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Windows-Azure-Active-Directory/Programming-Windows-Azure-Active-Directory-Deep-Dive) from Channel9. But the speaker has not shared the code which he used.

I wanted to authorize a MVC Controller with the help of Azure active directory.

Any help would be appreaciated.

**Update :**
The following blog my Geoff is really helpful.
http://geoffwebbercross.blogspot.co.uk/2014/05/adding-azure-ad-single-sign-on-to.html

Answer (score 2):

IMHO the best resources to start are:

- Overview of the scenarios you can tackle: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn499820.aspx
- Repos with all of our latest samples: https://github.com/AzureADSamples/

HTH!
V.